# How to display multiple images in same axes in matlab GUI GUIDE?

Tags: matlab-guide

Suppose I have 5 images like im1, im2, im3, im4, im5 and imshow functions are

imshow(im1,'Parent',handles.axes1);

imshow(im2,'Parent',handles.axes1);

imshow(im3,'Parent',handles.axes1);

imshow(im4,'Parent',handles.axes1);

imshow(im5,'Parent',handles.axes1);

But it displays only the last image im5 and previous images im1, im2, im3, im4 are not diplayed. Where is the wrong ? Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command to retain old graphs in an axes.

```
handles.axes1; hold on;
```

You can disable it by using.

```
handles.axes1; hold off;
```